# Path variable for coffeescript build in sublime on windows

Tags: windows, coffeescript, sublimetext2

So I have this build file

```
{
    "cmd": ["coffee", "-c", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.coffee",
    "path": "C:\\Users\\Miles\\node_modules\\coffee-script\\bin",
    "working_dir": "$project_path"
}
```

And it keeps on returning the error

[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

I have looked for a few days and and all I can find is unix based paths.

I know this is most likely trivial but it has been bugging be for a while

Comment: maybe using the full path ? "cmd": ["C:\\Users\\Miles\\node_modules\\coffee-script\\bin\\coffee.exe", "-c", "$file"]

Answer (score 3):

#### after a lot of tinkering this works fine.

```
{
    "cmd": ["coffee.cmd", "-c", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.coffee",
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "path": "$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH",
    "working_dir": "$project_path"
}
```

Comment: had the same problem and found this, pretty much the same thing but here is a more indepth look at it, http://kevinpelgrims.wordpress.com/2011/12/28/building-coffeescript-with-sublime-on-windows/